# SAS Enterprise Guide: Set a prompt both in Local and Metadata Server

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have a prompt that generate a variable across all my project (the SET_ENVIRONMENT macro variable).
I then run my programs on by one in my process flow.
The only problem is that some of them are local (when I want to upload data), and some of them are remote (using sas metadata server).

A solution would be to run my SET_PROMPT program twice, once on my local, once on my SAS Metadata Server.

I was wondering if it was possible to do set both prompts at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question.  You want to define `&SET_ENVIRONMENT.`, say assign it the value `COOKIE`, and have `&SET_ENVIRONMENT=COOKIE` be true in both local and your metadata server?   Or it would have two different values (perhaps `LOCAL` and `REMOTE`)?

Comment: COOKIE should be true in both local and metadata server

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with Metadata Server.  Is it similar to a SAS/CONNECT session?  Can you use %SYSRPUT to assign a macro variable on the Metadata Server?

Comment: I think it is a SAS/CONNECT session at the end of the day. All the SAS functions work the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this works like a SAS/CONNECT session, then what you might do is link your prompt to a program in the local session.  Have that program then be responsible for using %SYSRPUT to assign the variable on the metadata server, and have that program be always the first program you execute.  That way you don't need two prompts (which is annoying for the user) but get it assigned in two places at once.